How to view Docker /var/log files in AWS?
I have a github project which contains a Dockerfile that builds and launches two apps: react-app and node-server. My supervisord.conf file specifies the stdout logfile directory for both of these:
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:nginx]
command=nginx -g 'daemon off;'
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/nginx.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/nginx_err.log

[program:node-server]
command=node server.js
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/node_server.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/node_server_err.log

[program:react-app]
command=npm start
directory=/app
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/react_app.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/react_app_err.log


As you can see, lines like stdout_logfile=/var/log/react_app.log write log output to react_app.log.
When I build and run my Docker image locally and connect to the instance plus cd into /var/log/ and I can run commands like ls and cat to verify the log file is created and contains console.log statements.
I want to view the contents of these log files online, using AWS. When I visit the AWS page located at Amazon Elastic Container Service / Clusters / MyClusterCoolName / Services / MyCoolClusterServiceName / Logs I see logs, but these are only Dockerfile logs:

How can I make it so I can view the contents of my stdout_logfile online in AWS?

Typical practice would be to split these into three separate containers, and set the container processes to log to stdout and not to files.  The ECS console (or docker logs or kubectl logs) will capture containers' stdout, but reading logs out of files is much harder.

As mentioned above, you should be running one primary process per docker container, and that process should log to STDOUT instead of a file. Then you would see the log output in the AWS web console, and the logs could also be sent to AWS CloudWatch Logs for proper searching, alerts, etc. As it is, you would have to use ECS Exec to get to those log files inside the running container https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-exec.html
